# Prove that there exists $x$ such that $\lvert\det J\phi_x\rvert=1$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, multivariable-calculus

I would like some help on the following question.

> Let $\phi:B^k \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^k $ be a diffeomorphism and $\phi(B^k) = B^k$. Prove that there exists $x\in B^k$ such that $\lvert\det J\phi_x\rvert = 1$.
>
> ($B^k$ is the $k$ dimensional unit ball.)

I tried using the function $\phi(x) - x$ and showing it's Jacobian is zero at some point, but I think I need some kind of a vector function version of the mean value theorem.

Comment: You do know a mean value inequality, not equality. The hint is to proceed by contradiction.

Comment: *Hint.* $x \mapsto \left|\det J\phi_x\right|$ is continuous and satisfies $$1=\frac{1}{\operatorname{Vol}(B^k)}\int_{B^k}\left|\det J\phi_x\right|\,\mathrm{d}x.$$